# Questions about field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ be a field extension.

Some questions:

1. Can I write this as
   $$\{b_0 + b_1\sigma_1+\ldots b_{2^n - 1} \sigma_n: b_0,\ldots, b_{2^n-1}\in F\} $$
   where each $\sigma_i$ is the product of a different subset of ${\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n}$?
   Like, the only example of a field extension I've seen is $Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, and in the former, it's written as $\{b_1 + b_2\sqrt{2} + b_2\sqrt{3} + b_3\sqrt{6}: b_i\in Q\}$. Thus, I'm wondering if I can generalize the multiplication of elements part.
2. Is this equivalent to me saying
   $$
   F(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_{n-1}) = \{b_0 + b_1\alpha_1+\ldots b_{n-1}\alpha_{n-1}: b_0,\ldots, b_{n-1}\in F(\alpha_n)\}
   $$

If the second question is true, could I then just write
$$
[F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n): F] = [F(\alpha_{n}):F(\alpha_{n-1})][F(\alpha_{n-1}):F(\alpha_{n-2})]\ldots [F(\alpha_{1}):F]
$$

Not really sure exactly $\textbf{what}$ exactly a field extension is, as the textbook briefly skims over them, so I plan to read into it more and hopefully I'll realize this may just be a naïve/trivial question.

Comment: Have you seen $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$? What does a general element look like there? What do you think an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]3)$ looks like?

Comment: @Arthur I haven't, but if I were to guess I'd say $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \{b_0 + b_1\sqrt[3]{2}: b_0, b_1\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$ and that $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}) = \{b_0 + b_1\sqrt[3]{2}+ b_2\sqrt[3]{3}+ b_3\sqrt[3]{6}: b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has degree $3$, so the correct basis for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2\}$.  Then further extension by $\sqrt[3]{3}$ increases the basis up to $9$ elements.  ("Up to" because, in principle, $\sqrt[3]{3}$ or $(\sqrt[3]{3})^2$ could be in the span of the previous basis, although this doesn't happen here.)

Comment: @Obamafish Take a look at an infinite extension like $\mathbb{F}\subset \mathbb{F}(x)$, where the latter is the field of rational functions in $x$. Note that it is not spanned over $\mathbb{F}$ by a finite collection of rational functions. Moreover, if $\mathbb{F}$ is not countable (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), then $\mathbb{F}(x)$ is not spanned over $\mathbb{F}$ by a countable collection of rational functions.